# Natural numbers as types.

Tags: type-theory

My question could be simple but I haven't found an answer for it: could we define a type theory where the types are the natural numbers themselves (not the set of the natural numbers)?

Thanks.

Comment: what exactly do you mean by type theory?

Comment: I mean an Intuitionistic type theory or constructive type theory.

Comment: Do you mean something like the theory of simple types (TST)?

Comment: Ah, yes, thanks. I hadn't any idea about it.

Answer (score 1):

Most type system will have 1 or `True` the type with a single unique in habitant.

And they will have disjunction types so you can define Bool or 2 = 1 + 1. which  has two inhabitants..

In general you can have any sum 1 + 1 + 1 + 1 as a type and use 4 as a shorthand for it.

Therefore the natural numbers are already types in most systems.

Comment: A 0-tuple or record with no fields, i.e. an empty product type, are also common ways to describe the unit type. And of course an uninhabited type is 0.